# How do I place two methods together?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that asks the user for the name for the input and output. The code is to ask the user for the names of the input file and output file.   This will go into separate methods.  One will be called getInputFileName() and the other will be called getOutputFileName() and both will return String objects.  The method headers will be as follows:

```
public static String getInputFileName()

public static String getOutputFileName()
```

Both of these methods will ask the user to enter the appropriate file name and return that name as a String.  These methods will be called from the main method.  They return a String so it should have two String variables declared before the methods are called.

The rest of the program should be contained in another method.  This method header is as follows:

```
public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName)
```

I am trying to place the 2 methods `inputFileName` and `outputFile` name together, but i keep getting errors.

This is the program when they were separate methods:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WebberProject3Test1 {

private static Map<String, Integer> ticketTypeToPrice = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private static final String SPACE = " ";
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL = " $";



public static void getInputFileName() {
 // Create Scanner object for keyboard input. 
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Get the file name
    System.out.println("Enter the input filename here : ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Open the file.
    File file = new File(filename);
    System.out.println(filename);
}

public static void getOutputFileName() {
 // Create Scanner object for keyboard input. 
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Get the file name
    System.out.println("Enter the output filename here : ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Open the file.
    File file = new File(filename);
    System.out.println(filename);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    PrintWriter outputFile = null;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    getInputFileName();
    getOutputFileName();
    try {
        File file = new File("portlandvip2.txt");
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] entriesOnLine = line.split(" ");
            // Line with price and ticket type
            if (entriesOnLine.length == 2) {
                ticketTypeToPrice.put(entriesOnLine[0],    Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[1]));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(entriesOnLine[0])
                        .append(CURRENCY_SYMBOL)
                        .append(decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[1])));
                outputFile.println(sb.toString());
            } else if (entriesOnLine.length == 4) {
                //Line with First Name, Last Name, number of Tickets and Price
                int numberOfTickest = Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[2]);
                int ticketPrice = ticketTypeToPrice.get(entriesOnLine[3]);
                int totalPrice = numberOfTickest * ticketPrice;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(entriesOnLine[0])
                        .append(SPACE)
                        .append(entriesOnLine[1])
                        .append(CURRENCY_SYMBOL)
                        .append(decimalFormat.format(totalPrice));
                outputFile.println(sb.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + e);
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
}
```

This is the program after i try to place the methods together:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WebberProject3Test3 {

private static Map<String, Integer> ticketTypeToPrice = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private static final String SPACE = " ";
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL = " $";


final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String getInputFileName() {
System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
return scanner.nextLine();
}

public static String getOutputFileName() {
System.out.print("Enter output file: ");
return scanner.nextLine();
}

public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) 
{
Scanner scanner = null;
    PrintWriter outputFile = null;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    try {
        File file = new File(inputFileName);
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] entriesOnLine = line.split(" ");
            // Line with price and ticket type
            if (entriesOnLine.length == 2) {
                ticketTypeToPrice.put(entriesOnLine[0], Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[1]));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(entriesOnLine[0])
                        .append(CURRENCY_SYMBOL)
                        .append(decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[1])));
                outputFile.println(sb.toString());
            } else if (entriesOnLine.length == 4) {
                //Line with First Name, Last Name, number of Tickets and Price
                int numberOfTickest = Integer.parseInt(entriesOnLine[2]);
                int ticketPrice = ticketTypeToPrice.get(entriesOnLine[3]);
                int totalPrice = numberOfTickest * ticketPrice;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(entriesOnLine[0])
                        .append(SPACE)
                        .append(entriesOnLine[1])
                        .append(CURRENCY_SYMBOL)
                        .append(decimalFormat.format(totalPrice));
                outputFile.println(sb.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + e);
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
processTickets(getInputFileName(), getOutputFileName());
}
}
```

Comment: You can't nest methods.

Comment: if i cant nest methods then cant i place these two methods within a class together?

Comment: Yes you can. That is the right solution. You need to post the errors you are getting

Comment: You're instantiating a Scanner in each of your methods, but you never close either Scanner.

Comment: No, java 5-7 doesn't support nested NAMED methods.   You want nested, named methods in the JVM use Groovy or Scala

Comment: You can nest methods in Scala, just saying. It runs using the jvm aswell, and you can create projects with both scala and java code, using class from Scala files to create objects in Java. Its just a heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just misunderstanding the assignment. What you've tried to do is:

1. Create a `getInputFileName` that returns void
2. Create a `getOutputFileName` that returns void
3. Create a `main` method that does everything
4. Wrap all of the above into a `processTickets` method.

The point of the exercise is to make the program more modular by separating user input and processing, so what you should be doing is:

1. Create a `getInputFileName` that asks for and returns a String
2. Create a `getOutputFileName` that asks for and returns a String
3. Create a `processTickets` that takes two String filenames and processes them.
4. Create a `main` method that combines the three

Here's a framework piece of code to get started:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
  final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static String getInputFileName() {
    System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
    return scanner.nextLine();
  }

  public static String getOutputFileName() {
    System.out.print("Enter output file: ");
    return scanner.nextLine();
  }

  public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) {
    /* All your processing code here */
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    processTickets(getInputFileName(), getOutputFileName());
  }
}
```

---

The purpose of writing code this way is to be able to easily reuse and change programs.

For example, with just a few lines of code, we could rewrite the main method to allow running `java Test input.txt output.txt` in addition to just `java Test` and being prompted:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 2) {
      processTickets(args[0], args[1]);
    } else {
      processTickets(getInputFileName(), getOutputFileName());
    }
  }
```

These sort of changes are much harder when everything is one method.

Comment: i changed my post in order to show what the program looks like, and i wanted to know if i made the right changes to it or if there is still something i am doing wrong. When i compiled it there are no errors, but i am not entirely sure if i am right in my changes

Comment: @user3605753 You are still doing everything in the main method. Your main method should just be one line long (`processTickets(getInputFileName(), getOutputFileName());`), and everything else should be done in `processTickets`

Comment: i am trying to change the program based on what your telling me, but all i keep getting is the program asking for the input file name and then output file name and input file name again and so on in a infinite loop. I'll edit the post again to show what is different

Comment: @user3605753 1. Delete the `processTickets` call inside the `processTickets` method (this is what causes it to loop). 2. Use `new File(inputFileName)` instead of `new File("portlandvip2.txt")` (and likewise for output).

Comment: okay, i changed the post again. did i fix my previous errors? or is there still a problem with the code?

Comment: @user3605753 Your code writes to `"portland2out.txt"` instead of `outputFileName`, but other than that, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest methods this way.

Seems you want to call both methods in this order from within `processTickets`.

```
public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName){
    getInputFileName();
    getOutputFileName();
}
```

Also, I would try to reuse the same `Scanner` object. Creating a new `Scanner` in each of your methods is not a very good idea. Try making it a class variable, that would be OK in your case, and initialize it just once.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a method in a class, or a class in a class, but you can't put a method in a method. Make your methods / functions all declared at a higher level

```
public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) {
  // whatever you need to do for processing
}

public static String getInputFileName() {
  // Input filename handling
}

public static String getOutputFileName() {
  // Output filename handling
}
```

... and then...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    processTickets(getInputFileName(), getOutputFileName());
}
```

Comment: i have altered my initial post to show the new errors i am getting. What does the methods need to return in order to fix this new problem?

Comment: @user3605753: I don't see mention of *which* error you get.

Answer (score 0):

`getInputFileName` and `getOutputFileName` are useless unless you actually do something with the file name that they retrieve.

In the first version, you declared those methods as `void`.  You input a file name from the keyboard:

```
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
```

But that variable exists only within your method.  When the method is done, the `filename` goes away, and whatever input the user entered is thrown out.

In the second version, you changed the methods from `void` to `String`:

```
public static String getInputFileName() {
```

(As mentioned in the comments, you have to move them outside of `processTickets`.)  So now you've said that your `getInputFileName` method will return the file name as a `String`.  (That is, it will give the file name back to the method that called it.)  But you didn't return anything.  Java will give you an error message.  To get it to return the string you want, the method needs to have a `return` statement that returns the string you want it to return.

Adding a `return` does no good, however, if the method that calls it ignores the file name:

```
getInputFileName();
```

`getInputFileName` returns a file name, but the above statement tells it to just throw the file name away.  Not good.  You need to do something with the result, such as creating a new variable to hold the result.  You already did something like this when you said

```
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
```

and you need to do something similar in order to use the output of `getInputFileName()`.